# Is it possible to use w3.css with Vaadin?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, vaadin8, w3.css

I just have learned about vaadin and I'm watching tutorial about a CRUD TODO list in youtube. Vaadin uses Valo theme for css rendering that I found great but I'm wondering is it possible to use w3.css framework within vaadin vue code ?

I try googling but no answers.

Comment: No. There are other ways to build responsive layouts/apps with vaadin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*It depends™*

If you are asking: can is just replace *Valo* with *W3.css* the answer is most likely no, at least out of the box.  The reason for this is, that Vaadin client side code emits the HTML-code you see in the browser and all `style` and `class` tags there are defined on their end.  So what any theme for Vaadin must do, is to provide styling rules for that exact schema; so you would have to find a way to adapt. Or you have to put `addStyleName` all over your code (if it's `btn` in your CSS framework, it's `v-button` in Vaadin and also nested elements might be different etc).

Yet, if you just want to use the styles for some parts of your application (let's say, you want a fancy start page or add *cards* etc), then you can *add* the other CSS and use them together.  Vaadin/Valo does a good job in isolating their styles from the rest of the page and also within their hierarchy (the theme name is a prefix to all Valo rules). Yet if the two themes then look great together is another story, but Valo itself allows for quite some tweaking just with variables put in SASS.